# Parse PFAnalytics not tracking push opens

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've set up my app to receive push notifications sent from Parse, following all the steps in Parse's documentation:

https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications

When running on my mobile devices, the app receives every single push notification I send to it from Parse, but push opens are not being tracked. This is what I see on the dashboard:

[image]

Given that [`PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions` and `PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload`](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFAnalytics.html) return their respective [`BFTasks`](http://boltsframework.github.io/docs/ios/Classes/BFTask.html), I've added a completion block for them as follows:

In `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification`:

```
PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo).continueWithBlock({ (task) -> AnyObject! in

    assert(task.completed, "task should have completed")

    assert(!task.cancelled, "task should not have been cancelled")

    assert(!task.faulted, "task should not complete due to error or exception")

    return task
})
```

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions).continueWithBlock({ (task) -> AnyObject! in

    assert(task.completed, "task should have completed")

    assert(!task.cancelled, "task should not have been cancelled")

    assert(!task.faulted, "task should not complete due to error or exception")

    return task
})
```

The continuations block do get called, but none of the `asserts` fail, so `PFAnalytics` is supposedly successfully sending the data to Parse Analytics.

Why are my push opens and open rate still zero?

Answer (score 2):

Bug filed and confirmed by Facebook: 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/119817525037600/

Comment: And closed without providing any solution :(

Answer (score 0):

I have realized that push opens get tracked if you look for the "Push Opens" event in the Analytics section, but no information are given on the single Push campaign, making A/B testing totally useless at the moment.